# Sum the column in SSIS and send email

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a table where I need to sum 2 columns (Salary and Bonus) and email them 
 off using SSIS. I somehow managed to write a script to send an email but unable to sum 2 columns in C#.

```
    public void Main()

            {
                String SendMailFrom = Dts.Variables["EmailFrom"].Value.ToString();
                String SendMailTo = Dts.Variables["EmailTo"].Value.ToString();
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("bbb"));
                msg.From = new MailAddress("ccc");
                msg.Body = "Process is completed successfully.
                               1) Sum of Salary is 1234 
                               2)Sum of Bonus is 1234
                               3) Count of distinct Accounts is 123";//This is the requirement
                msg.Subject = "XYZ PROCESS";
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
                OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("xxx");
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx");
                client.Port = 587; 
                client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
                client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                try
                {
                    dbConnection.Open();

                    if (dbConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        OleDbCommand dbCommand = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
                        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SUM([Salary]),Sum([Bonus]) FROM table";
                        OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();

                        if (dbReader.HasRows)
                            dtResults.Load(dbReader);

                        string theSum = dtResults.Rows[0]["TOTAL"].ToString();
                        dbReader.Close();
                        dbConnection.Close();
                        client.Send(msg);
                        MessageBox.Show("Email was Successfully Sent ");

                    }
                }



                //try
                //{
                //    client.Send(msg);
                //    MessageBox.Show("Email was Successfully Sent ");
                //}
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Unable to execute query as requested.", ex);
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

                //{
                //    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                //}
            }

            #region ScriptResults declaration
            /// <summary>
            /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
            /// result of the script.
            /// 
            /// This code was generated automatically.
            /// </summary>
            enum ScriptResults
            {
                Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
                Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
            };
            #endregion

        }
    }
```

I am not expert in writing C# scripts and would appreciate the help

Comment: And the error is?

Comment: there is no error as script task is getting executed. But I am not sure how to perform the sql query "SELECT SUM([Salary]),Sum([Bonus]) FROM table" capture the output and attach the output in msg.Body

Comment: I answered below, but why don't you just run this code outside SSIS and debug it?  Then you will know where the error is.  Also you don't want to show a MessageBox when running within SSIS.

Comment: You are building out `msg` with what I assume you're going to populate with values from your query. However, you're never using the value of `theSum` after assignment. Your query never computes the count of accounts either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, decompose your problems into smaller units until you have something you can solve.

I would create a method called BuildMessageBody. This will run your query and slice out the elements you want and then use the string.Format method to substitute into your message, by ordinal position, the values you want.

```
public string BuildMessageBody()
{
    // Create a message template that will 
    string template = @"Process is completed successfully.
                   1) Sum of Salary is {0}
                   2) Sum of Bonus is {1}
                   3) Count of distinct Accounts is {2}";
    string query = @"SELECT SUM(T.[Salary]) AS TotalSalary, Sum(T.[Bonus]) AS TotalBonus, COUNT(DISTINCT T.AccountNumber) AS UniqueAccounts FROM table AS T";

    string totalSalary = string.Empty;
    string totalBonus = string.Empty;
    string uniqueAccounts = string.Empty;
    string body = string.Empty;

    using(OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection("xxx"))
    {
        dbConnection.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, dbConnection))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            using (OleDbDataReader  reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // This should only ever yield one row due to aggregation in source query
                // But this implementation will result in the last row (arbitrary source sorting)
                // being preserved
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Access by ordinal position
                    totalSalary = reader[0].ToString();
                    totalBonus = reader[1].ToString();
                    uniqueAccounts = reader[2].ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        // At this point, we should have results
        body = string.Format(template, totalSalary, totalBonus, uniqueAccounts);
    }

    return body;
}
```

Your original code then replaces the assignment of `msg.Body` to be

```
msg.Body = BuildMessageBody();
```

and then you can get rid of all your data access code in your ScriptMain (the try block) but keep `client.Send(msg);` or you'll never send email.

Comment: The above code is approximately correct. Freehand manipulation of existing code to fit the specifics of the question

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are getting an error in your code on this line because there is no TOTAL column in your query:

```
string theSum = dtResults.Rows[0]["TOTAL"].ToString();
```

Modify your SQL query and it might work (You will want to add a total for both sums) I just added for Bonus:

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SUM([Salary]),Sum([Bonus]) as TOTAL FROM table";
```

And also as billinkc mentions, you never do anything with `theSum` in your email.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your SUM "columns" names. Like Rick said, you reference the "TOTAL" column but there is no TOTAL column. You are querying 2 sums/totals though so they both need names and you will need to grab both in your code and format them in the email however you want.

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SUM([Salary]) As SalaryTotal, Sum([Bonus]) As BonusTotal FROM table";

string theSum1 = dtResults.Rows[0]["BonusTotal"].ToString();
string theSum2 = dtResults.Rows[0]["SalaryTotal"].ToString();
```

Comment: then how do I write my msg.body? because my msg.body needs to be something like "This process is successfully completed and the sum of salary is 123 and the sum of bonus is 234"